# Complexity in different approaches to solve a problem

Tags: python

I wrote two different python programs to check if a number is Armstrong or not. Which approach is better and has less complexity?

First Approach:

```
def isArmstrong(n):
    temp = n
    length=len(str(n))
    sum1,digit=0,0
    while n>0:
       digit = n%10
       n = n//10
       sum1 += digit**length
    if sum1==temp:
        print('Armstrong No')
    else:
       print('Not an Armstrong no')
isArmstrong(371)
```

Second Approach:

```
def isArmstrong(n):
    n=str(n)
    sum=0
    for i in n:
        sum += int(i)**len(n)
     if str(sum)==n:              #Edited After Reading Comments
         print('No is Armstrong')
     else:
         print('No is not Armstrong')

isArmstrong(371)
```

Comment: How do you define that number is `Armstrong`?

Comment: I think he's referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number).

Comment: @Andrej Kesely It's also called narcissistic numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number

Comment: As an example for a no 371,if 3^3+7^3+1^3=371 then it is an Armstrong number.

Comment: Have you tried characterizing it in time and memory complexity?

Comment: Same complexity but I prefer the first version as it is the only one that works. (the second version compares an int to an integer and will always print 'No is not Armstrong') `if sum==n`

Comment: @SaranshKhurana note that you won't need to compare the string values if you don't overwrite the input value `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both algorithms have the same [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), but you should prefer the second as it is way more readable.

You also could simplify it like this:

```
def isArmstrong(n):
    l = len(str(n))
    return sum(int(i)**l for i in str(n)) == n

print(isArmstrong(153)) # >> True
```

> NB: There is a mistake in your second solution: `sum==n` will always be False, since `n` is a string and `sum` an integer. Also, `sum` is a reserved keyword, you should'nt use it as a variable name.

**Edit:**

If you **really** need the maximum performance, so yeah, the first solution is  faster from a few nanoseconds, I think that's because it avoids an `int` conversion which seems to be a little more expensive than the division of solution 1.

But if you can spare one or two nanoseconds, I definitly advice you the two others, because they are far more readable, and in python: [Readability counts.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

As you cansee, for 100.000 iterations, the difference is very low:

```
import timeit

def isArmstrong1(n):
    temp = n
    length = len(str(n))
    sum1, digit = 0, 0
    while n>0:
        digit = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        sum1 += digit ** length
    return sum1 == temp

def isArmstrong2(n):
    n0, n = n, str(n)
    sum_ = 0
    for i in n:
        sum_ += int(i) ** len(n)
    return sum_ == n0

def isArmstrong3(n):
    sn = str(n)
    ln = len(sn)
    return sum(int(i)**ln for i in sn) == n

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong1(1), number=100000)) # >> 0.16810399199999998
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong2(1), number=100000)) # >> 0.15370833699999997
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong3(1), number=100000)) # >> 0.16646642300000003

print("---")

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong1(153), number=100000)) # >> 0.208019595
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong2(153), number=100000)) # >> 0.375219658
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong3(153), number=100000)) # >> 0.36911681499999993

print("---")

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong1(9474), number=100000)) # >> 0.2775220709999999
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong2(9474), number=100000)) # >> 0.407324241
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: isArmstrong3(9474), number=100000)) # >> 0.377674313
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would be **at least** `O([log n]^2)` because `str(n)` is being evaluated `len(str(n))` times, whereas both of OP's solutions are bound from below by `O(log n)`. (Assuming `str(n) = Ω(log n)`)

Comment: Right, but I don't think the complexity of the algorithm really matters here, it's a very simple operation. However, `len(str(n))` could easily be computed before if performance really matters...

Comment: what if i compare it like this: str(sum1)==n??. Edit: I am considering sum1 as sum is reversed keyword.

Comment: I agree that this small optimisation is likely to be unimportant in practice, just thought OP should be aware of this quirk in case e.g. they are attempting a programming challenge with a time restriction.

Comment: Fine, that's done. I'm not 100% sure OP was really speaking about time complexity, thought...

Comment: @olinox14 The complexity might be same, but in practice when I tested the two solutions with `timeit`, the first method is approx 1,7x faster..

Comment: I am practicing it for a hiring challenge where time and space complexity should be minimum.

Comment: @AndrejKesely think I'll go with the first method then.

Comment: @Saransh Khurana Yes you could do `str(sum1)==n`, or `sum1==int(n)`, or even store the initial `n` value (best option if performance really matters)...